# Background video not supported on mobile?

Tags: html, css, sass, html5-video

For the website of a client I put a video on home but this is not showing up on mobile.

I saw multiple docs that video's aren't supported on mobile. I find it weird because I regularly see websites with video's that work on mobile. Does somebody know a way around this?

I tried multiple file formats but nothing seems to do the trick.

My code;

```
<video class="hero__video" loading="lazy" autoplay="on load" 
muted="muted" loop="loop" poster="65bf2fb45c0e8d3579f14cd9da76a2b0.jpg">
<source src="video-banner.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Webvelopment Your question is not answerable, and your code does not help us to recreate your problem. Things to fix... **(1)** What browser on what mobile? **(2)** Your claim also needs a testable `video-banner.webm` for checking the problem. **PS** Possible solution is to provide multiple `<source>` tags for different formats then the browser itself chooses one it can play. See example code at:  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video (they use MP4 and OGG, but you want to offer choices of MP4 and WebM). This means converting a copy of your video.

Comment: @VC.One (1) for exempel safari does not show the video on mobile. (2) What do you mean by a testable video?

Here you can find the live site: https://www.lakookaburra.com

Comment: Yeah Safari and MP4/MOV is from Apple and then Chrome and WebM is from Google. You'll notice Google's own video format (webm) works on Chrome but Chrome will not play Apple's own MOV format. The same is true on Apple side, meaning no (reliable) WebM support in Safari (it might work on desktop but then not on mobile etc). **(2)** In your website code, try putting the MP4 as first/top on the list (of those 3 video formats listed) then try playing it on Safari mobile. You don't need MOV (it's good for other things like containing a video with some transparent pixels, or Apple specific codecs)

Comment: @VC.One thanks for your answer. I removed the MOV and put MP4 as first source. Still does not do the trick. Is there maybe an other solution? I hope you can help...

Comment: I see you've updated the code now (will delete Answer). Is the problem solved?

Comment: @VC.One no the problem is not fixed... I've got a blank hero now when the video is loaded. Did open the web inspector for mobile safari but can't see what is causing the problem...

Comment: @VC.One EDIT: it seems like he is blocking the video. if I inspect the source code  it's grey instead of colored

Comment: **(1)** Try adding **Plays Inline** option `preload="none" playsinline="playsinline"` **(2)** It's possible autoplay is being blocked. Is the device's battery fully charged when you test (in case something like [Low Power Mode is preventing autoplay](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54379718/2057709)).